# Run python3 in atom with atom-runner

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, atom-editor

I am trying to run simple python code in atom using atom-runner package, but I am getting following error:

> Unable to find command: python
>
> Are you sure PATH is configured correctly?

How can I configure PATH. (path to my python is `C:\Python34`)

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: If you install Python you can choose "add Python to PATH". This will *probably* fix it. Try running the Python3.4 installer again and make sure you tick this box (it's off by default, if I remember correctly).

Comment: Thank you very much :) It worked. I had to choose "Add Python to environment variables"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the start menu, and select System. Then, hit "Advanced system settings" > "Environment Variables". Click on path, and hit edit. Select "New" and add the folder that your python executable is in. That should fix the problem.

Your other option is to reinstall python and select "add PYTHON to PATH" as Carpetsmoker suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If this does not work guys uninstall Python and Atom. While reinstalling Python make sure you click on "Add Python to Path" so you will not have any problems with setting the paths at all!